# Find the a < 0 for which the inequalities have at least one common solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the $a < 0$ for which the inequalities $\hspace{0.5cm}2\sqrt{ax}<3a—x\hspace{0.5cm}$ and $\hspace{0.5cm}x-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}>\frac{6}{a}\hspace{0.5cm}$ have at least one solutions in common.

I don't know how to begin

Please give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one to make sense, you need $x\lt 3a$. Then square both sides: $$4ax \lt 9a^2 +x^2 -6ax \\ x^2 -10ax +9a^2 \gt 0 \\ (x-9a)(x-a) \gt 0 $$  Since $x$ cannot be greater than $a$, it must be that case that $$x\lt 9a$$ The second one is $$\sqrt{ \frac xa} \lt x-\frac 6 a $$ For this to make sense, you need $x\gt \frac 6a $. Try to do a similar thing now as I did, keeping in mind the restriction. Once you get the two solution sets, you can see what $a$ must be for there to be non-zero intersection between them.

Comment: Why x cannot be greater than a?

Comment: @SharanyaSingh Because $x\lt 3a$, which is more negative than $a$.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $x<0$ and remember that multiplying/dividing with negative number changes the inequality sign.

You can rewrite you sytem like this, multiply second by $a$ and you get $$xa-\sqrt{ax} -6>0$$

so $$(\sqrt{ax} -3)(\sqrt{ax} +2)<0 \implies \sqrt{ax} <3$$ First inequality is equivalent to $$( \sqrt{x} +3 \sqrt{a})( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}) \implies  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{a}$$

So $${9\over a}<x<a \implies a^2<9 \implies a\in (-3,0)$$